# Keep unique values in an array based on another array while preserving order

Tags: python, numpy

I have two array `my_arr` and `distances`. For example:

```
my_arr= np.array([0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5])
distances = np.array([18, 47, 20, 10, 26, 22, 13])
```

I would like to get an array of indices whose shape is `np.unique(my_arr).size` based on the minimum distance. So in the previous example, I would get:

```
# indices of my_arr
indices_of_my_arr= np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6])
```

Except `for` loops or `map` is there a clever way to do this?

**EDIT:**
Another example:

```
my_arr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5])
dist = np.array([10, 12, 15, 18, 5, 14, 45, 8])
```

I expect:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) and [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
idx = np.lexsort([distances, my_arr])
out = np.sort(idx[np.unique(my_arr[idx], return_index=1)[1]])
```

Comment: I have added another example because your solution does not yield the expected array.

Comment: @floflo29 Had to add in sort there. Check out the edit.